# Работа с сервисом Gravatar на PHP

Tags: php, gravatar

Добрый вечер, всем. Сейчас делаю комментарии к товарам моего учебного интернет-магазина на PHP. И при оформлении комментариев задался таким вопросом - как мне зная email пользователя, который оставил комментарий, получить его аватар с сервиса Gravatar? Подскажите, пожалуйста решение.

Comment: забавно, рука злобного минусатора, орудовавшего тут несколько минут назад, не добралась до ответов. Неужто репа упала до сотни?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда уж так:

http://ru.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/

Answer (score 1):

https://ru.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

https://ru.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/

Comment: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".sha1($email) - не заработало(((

Comment: Там вообще то md5

"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5($email)